# How to use default react state as state provider instead of redux or mobx?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4, mobx

I am experiencing some serious fatigue when I tried wiring up redux with react router vs mobx with react router. I also tried to wire up a top level state with router's `render` func, but since router do not refresh, that method will fail. My state management requirement is rather simple and I am feeling redux or mobx are overkill. All I really need is a top-level state provider that acts as if just like any other component level state and use callback a way to manipulate it.

Been googling and looking at different solutions for the whole morning, however, I can't find a readily available solution with default react state that can work with react router (v4).

Is there a solution avaible? or its really something not possible to do when it comes to state with react router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you setup Mobx? Maybe you're overthinking it. You can setup a top-level observable object that pretty much mimics the standard component state, but with all benefits of reactive programming.

If you use the `<Provider>` wrapper component from the `mobx-react` package that store becomes accessible to all your child components using `@inject`. In combination with `@observer` any component that depends on your store will update when you change it.

Check out this code sandbox example I created to showcase this for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jzv73o97r5

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with react router v6 it has some optimistic approach to do so

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).